# Text disappears when changing the font

Tags: user-interface, windbg

When I change the font in WinDbg, the text disappears. I have to restart WinDbg to see text again, but then, the font setting is gone.

Before:

[image: Screenshot Before]

After changing the Font to Lucida Console 14:

[image: Screenshot After]

Version at the time of writing: WinDbg 10.0.10586.567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be 2 questions:

1. How can I get the color back without restarting
2. How do I save the font in the workspace

### Get the color back

This only happens in customized workspaces like yours. The text is not really gone but its color seems to be reset to black. The text is still there and can be selected:

[image: WinDbg with selected text]

To partially fix this, you can go to the View/Options menu, select the text color entry (no need to change) and click Ok.

[image: View/Options]

Doing so might be needed twice:

- when the focus is in the output window
- when the focus is in the command prompt

Doing that will not affect the readability of existing text but the output of any new commands will be displayed in green color again.

[image: Final result]

### Store the font in the Workspace

WinDbg knows several workspaces and when you chose "Save Workspace" it probably saved into a very specific one (specific to an executable or a crash dump).

To have the font settings always, it needs to be saved in the "base" Workspace. To do that:

- open WinDbg without running a program and without opening a dump file
- change the font
- set the color again
- save the Workspace (File / Save Workspace)

In some versions of WinDbg, e.g. 6.3.9600, this does not seem to be enough. In that case,

- open WinDbg without running a program and without opening a dump file
- change the font
- set the color again
- set the window to restored size (i.e. not maximized)
- move the window to a different position
- save the Workspace (File / Save Workspace)
- maximize the window (if you want it maximized)
- save the Workspace again (if you want it maximized)